# Autoboxing not to wrapper

Tags: java, autoboxing

```
Object a = 3;
System.out.println(a.getClass().getName());
```

Why a is Integer now? Why not incompatible types compilation error? Java Tutorials clearly states:

> Autoboxing is the automatic conversion that the Java compiler makes between the primitive types and their corresponding object wrapper classes.

Why Java autobox '3' to Integer in the case?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This applies for most any other object you come across; so long as there is a common ancestor between two objects, you can assign one to another.  This is known as [**is-a**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Is-a), and is so named because of the question it answers. `Integer` **is an** `Object`.

Autoboxing simply takes a primitive type and converts it to an object wrapper representation of itself. No information is lost, and the compiler is coercing a primitive into something that is an `Object`.  Thus, your assignment is legal.

If there *isn't* a direct relationship between the two objects, then you would get a compilation error.

For instance:

```
String a = 3;
```

...would result in a compilation error, since `Integer` can't be assigned to `String`.

[You may peruse other autoboxing rules here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.1.7), but one further thing:  all non-decimal numbers are presumed to be `int` unless they're suffixed with `L` or `l`, in which case they're `long`.

Answer (score 2):

I don't see any reason why there should be a compilation error. Once the primitive type `3` in this case is autoboxed to its wrapper type `Integer`, there should not be any compilation error because `Integer` implicitly inherits from `Object`, meaning you can easily assign any object of type `Integer` to type `Object`.

> I don't understand why primitive type '3' is autoboxed to its wrapper
>   type Integer.

It has to be autoboxed, otherwise, you cannot assign a primitive type to a type `Object`. Since the receiving type is a type `Object` ( a *reference* type) then the *primitive* type has to be autoboxed to make it compatible. Thus you can assign a *reference* type to a *reference* type.

Comment: To extend the answer, you could also use `Number` since `Integer` also inherits from it. However you could not use `LinkedList` or something like this. You can always *lower the view* to an object, this is all that happens here. For example `Object obj = new LinkedList<>();` or `Collection c = new LinkedList<>();` works too.

Comment: I understand this. I don't understand why primitive type '3' is autoboxed to its wrapper type Integer.

Comment: If possible **Java** tries to autobox `int` to `Integer` and `Integer` to `int` whereever needed, that is whenever something needs an object instead of a datatype or vice versa (the same holds for the other types). In your code a `Object` is needed so **Java** tries to autobox `int` to `Integer` and it works.